# Can't select correct field from control source dropdown

Tags: ms-access

I have an Access form. On the underlying query for my form, there are two tables, A and B. Both tables have a field named "Customer". When I was testing my form, I noticed that I somehow had A.Customer as the control source for a particular field when I really wanted B.Customer. So I tried to change it. As soon as I select B.Customer from the control source dropdown and save the form, the field control source reverts to A.Customer. I can save the control source to be any other field in my query or any calculation I can think of, but if I try to save it as B.Customer it becomes A.Customer. Variants like [B].[Customer] make no difference. I've tried saving it as a random calculated field, closing and reopening the database, then saving it as B.Customer, but it still turns into A.Customer. What is going on here?

If it makes any difference, I do dynamically change the RecordSource for this form during operation. I've aliased my table names to A and B (SELECT DISTICTROW A.*, B.* FROM [Table With A Long Name] AS A RIGHT JOIN [Table With An Even Longer Name] AS B ON A.ID = B.AID) because I was running into character limits on the RecordSource property when changing it. I certainly never had this problem using the non-aliased table names.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ah, just deleting and recreating the field fixed this. Carry on.